# cordova - error with context trying to display alert or toast

Tags: java, android, cordova

In my Cordova plugin I'm tried to display a toast or an alert but wasn't able to get the context of the application. In my onTagWithRssiReceived() function - which is an override function - I could display all the values I wanted in the Eclipse log, but when I try to use toast or an alert my application would crash.

I tried to set my context with:

```
Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

but I got the error: "cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field."

Also I used:

```
Context c = ctx.getApplicationContext();
```

but even though there's no visible errors in Eclipse it would still crash my program.

Finally, I tried ((Activity)ctx) and it worked perfectly.

Here is my Java code:

```
public class HelloPlugin extends Plugin implements iRcpEvent2, OnCompletionListener, IOnHandlerMessage {

public static final String NATIVE_ACTION_STRING = "nativeAction";
public static final String SUCCESS_PARAMETER = "success";
public int maxTags = 1;
public int maxTime = 100;
public int repeatCycle = 0;

public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray dataArray,
        String callbackId) {

    if (NATIVE_ACTION_STRING.equals(action)) {

        String resultType = null;
        try {
            resultType = dataArray.getString(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("HelloPlugin", ex.toString());
        }

        if (resultType.equals(SUCCESS_PARAMETER)) {

            RcpApi2 rcpAPI = RcpApi2.getInstance();
            rcpAPI.setOnRcpEventListener(this);

            try {
                boolean t = rcpAPI.open();

                if (t = true) {
                    try {

                        boolean k = rcpAPI.startReadTagsWithRssi(maxTags,
                                maxTime, repeatCycle);

                        if (k = true) {     

                            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, k);

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                                "Context not set properly :(");
                    }
                } else {
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                            "Reader Not Opened :(");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                    "Oops, Error :(");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTagWithRssiReceived(int[] arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String epc = toHexString(arg0); 
    String p = Integer.toString(arg1);
    byte[] epcToByteArray = RcpLib.convertStringToByteArray(epc);

    int accessPassword = 00000000;
    int startAddress = 0;
    int targetLength = 0;

    RcpApi2 rcpAPI = RcpApi2.getInstance();

    boolean tid = rcpAPI.readFromTagMemory(
            Long.parseLong(Integer.toString(accessPassword), 16),
                RcpLib.convertStringToByteArray(epc),
                0,
                Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(startAddress), 16),
                targetLength);

    Log.d("EPC:", epc);
    Log.d("EPCTOBYTEARRAY:", epcToByteArray.toString());
    Log.d("RETURNFROMTAGMEMORY:", Boolean.toString(tid));
    Log.d("RSSI:", p);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(((Activity)ctx));
    builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();

}
}
```

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but it is possible that reviewing this plugin code maybe useful to you: https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer/blob/master/src/android/VideoPlayer.java tldr; have an overload of the execute method that accepts the context and then calls to your plugin specific methods.

Comment: Thanks Dawson. Since it's a PhoneGap plugin and I'm using javascript to communicate with it, I'm not sure where the execute method is being called. I think there's PhoneGap magic happening there. So if I overload it I don't know where I would pass the context through as an additional parameter, and I wouldn't know how to implement the overloaded method.

Comment: Also, thanks for sharing your plugin. Unfortunately I get an error when I try to do something like... this.cordova.getActivity() - could be because I'm using an older version of cordova, but not entirely sure.